# MongoDB - How to get a document with a count of children

Tags: mongodb

I have a document structure like this one:

```
{ 
  _id:
  name:
  parent:
}
```

I have the documents that some of them have a parentID (like a tree). I want to get one document based on the ID, but also the count of children that specific document has.

for example:

```
{ 
  _id:1
  name: 1
  parent:
}
{ 
  _id:2
  name: 2
  parent: 1
}
{ 
  _id:3
  name: 3
  parent: 1
}
```

I want to find by id 1 and get something like this

```
{ 
  _id:1
  name: 1
  parent:
  childCount: 2
}
```

Is this possible?

Kind regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do self `$lookup` to get the children count

```
db.tp1.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {from:"tp1", localField : "_id", foreignField: "parent", as: "children"}},
    {$addFields:{children : {$size : "$children"}}}
])
```

result

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : 1, "parent" : null, "children" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : 2, "parent" : 1, "children" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : 3, "parent" : 1, "children" : 0 }
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without $lookup operator @saravana?
It worked like charm in local nut I'm using DocumentDB in AWS and believe it or not, it doesn't support that feature. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis-aggregation-pipeline.html

Comment: you can do `$group` by `parent` and `$count` children